# Printing the given value using DMA

Tags: c, dynamic, realloc

I'm coding to get the value of given number in Dynamic method using realloc. In this case the O/P of new size elements is not printing the correct value. Its printing some unknown garbage values after one or two elements.

This program to resize the integer value in the run time.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        int *ptr,n,newsize;

        printf("Enter size Elements\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        ptr = (int*) malloc (n * sizeof(int));

        printf("Enter the Elements\n");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", ptr+i);
        }
        printf("Elements are\n");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("%u\n", *(ptr+i));
        }

        printf("Enter the New Size of the Elements\n");
        scanf("%d", &newsize);

        ptr = realloc(ptr,newsize);

        printf("Enter the new Elements\n");
        for(int i=0;i<newsize;i++)
        {
        scanf("%d", ptr+newsize);
        }
        printf("New Elements are\n");
        for(int i=0;i<newsize;i++)
        {
            printf("%u\n", *(ptr+i));
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Expecting:

```
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

Actual Results:

```
    1
    2
    4566745
    4534665
```

Comment: `for(int i=n; i<newsize; i++) scanf("%d", ptr+i);`

Comment: `%u` is the format specifier for printing `unsigned`,, use `%d` instead.

Comment: Note that `ptr = realloc(ptr,newsize);` exemplifies an anti-pattern in C.  If the `realloc()` fails (and you should check, every time!), then you've lost your pointer to the previously allocated memory — a memory leak.  Use `newptr = realloc(oldptr, newsize);` and test that `newptr` is not null before assigning it over `oldptr`.

Comment: Also note that you initially allocate `ptr = (int*) malloc (n * sizeof(int));` but you subsequently allocate using `ptr = realloc(ptr,newsize);`.  You've forgotten to multiply by `sizeof(int)`, so you shrank your array, and trampled out of bounds.  Use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) to find problems like that if it is available on your system.

Comment: Also, there's no benefit to using the `*(ptr+i)` notation — use `ptr[i]`; it is simpler and clearer.

Comment: Will follow your valuable comments in the future @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 1):

Its working now after making below correction said by Johnny Mopp.

```
printf("New Elements are\n");
    for(int i=0;i<newsize;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", *(ptr+i));
    }
```